# Clicking on full site loads mobile chat again

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks, mobile-web

I was switching from mobile chat to full site to upload an image on chat room on my mobile. Clicking on full site still gives mobile chat after a page refresh.

I tried several times but the result is same.

Browser : Google Chrome
Version : 79.0.3945.93

Comment: Reproduced, using the Tavern on the Meta, Google Chrome 79.something, Android 9, Samsung Galaxy a10s.

Comment: @Rob not sure what you mean and how it's related? The "mobile" and "full site" links in chat just stopped working, looks like whatever JS code was attached to them in the past has been lost.

Comment: That is a feature of the Chrome browser, not the SE site.  It doesn't happen with browsers like Brave when 'desktop site' setting is on.

Comment: @Chenmunka - Yet the "full site" button on other SE sites (including MSE itself) works just fine for me; it seems to be just chat that's not working.

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard There's [two sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYKj9.jpg) for FF; as Chenmunka and Mithical mentioned, YMMV.

Comment: @Rob I was able to switch to full site in chat and main site without requesting full site in my browser. I only clicked full site option everytime. It worked yesterday too.

Comment: Here's the easiest way to explain it (rather than searching for an old comment that might be deleted) using **a completely different example**: Notice that [on the Profile page, for uploading an Avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rnj0.jpg), that the Browser can be set to "Desktop Site" ***but*** if **the website** isn't toggled into "Full Site" that the operation of the site is different - in the left pane you can't upload an Avatar, in the right pane you can. **But** when you try to switch on *that* page it simply reloads; you need to be on one of the two **other** tabs to switch.

Comment: I've mentioned this in a few places. I noticed it happening a few days ago in mobile Safari. I can get to the full site view by toggling it in the browser settings but not using the full site link in the menu.

Comment: @Catija This is working for me now. Can you check with some developer and add a [tag:status-completed].